# windows.location.reload() in api response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests library. I want to get API response of one API.

API response in postman is json response and its all good. 
But when I request using python it gives following response:

```
<html><script lang=javascript>\r\ndocument.cookie = '_accessKey2=l-Eq2NxKAO5vjLCmB2KmDWCfOv30Nvjp'\r\nwindow.location.reload();\r\n</script></html>\r\n"
```

API was working fine till yesterday. Is the issue at API end or my end?

Comment: Looks like you maybe don't pass the right cookie? Or maybe it's sending you a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the api provider expects appropriate headers try this

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=YourData, headers=headers)
```

Comment: `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own quesion.

This happens when api needs some sort of headers to retrieve the data. In my case it needed following header:

```
headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Cookie": ""}
```

And then you can do

```
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```